# How IP messenger populates online users

Tags: java, android, udp, ip, messenger

I am developing IP messenger(LAN messenger) for android,

Successfully able to send data using udp. But I have to manually type the target IP address.

Now I am trying to create a list of online users.

How do IP messenger populates online users?

Comment: You need a way that will allow your clients to exchange their IP addresses. Are you using a server in the Middle tier ?

Comment: no i am not using a server in between.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to :

> Make Clients Ping the Server in frequent intervals
>
> At the server side , update the list of users based on the `ping` received from client